# Насколько нагружает preg_replace?

Tags: php

Использую `preg_replace` для преобразования статьи перед выводом - необходимое действие в текущей ситуации. Хотел узнать, не убьет сервер при условии обработки статей до 50 000 символов?

Comment: Регулярки в php реализованы не как конструкция языка а как функция по этому они поедают кучу памяти, и стоит с осторожнстью их использования. Но если вы собираетесь использовать это в административной части тут можно. Но опять же если вы собираетесь править html таким образом то лучший путь построить dom дерево html изменить элемент и сохранить всё как html

Comment: От регулярки сильно зависит. проверяйте конретно на своих примерах. замеряйте скорость.

Comment: @Naumov, то есть, использовать класс DomDocument - так будет работать быстрее?

Comment: Любой класс работающий с dom тут к стати был ответ по поводу регулярок и html http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: @Naumov, мне вот работа с HTML посредством построения DOM-дерева видится более сложной для сервера. Сначала нужно разобрать HTML-код на теги, потом пройти по ним циклом и выполнить какие-то действия. Сам по себе разбор HTML - уже довольно сложный процесс... Действительно ли, это лучше, чем использовать `preg_replace`? И, раз уж на то пошло, есть возможность перед сохранением статьи подготовить ее к использованию при выводе `str_replace` вместо `preg_replace`. Будет ли этот вариант быстрее предыдущих двух (включая разбор HTML-кода)?

Comment: Это всё кастыли, а регулярка как работает перебирая строку по символам (в зависимости от того какой патерн естевственно). это на много тяжелее, да и ненадёжно всё это так как заменой регуляркой можно ошибиться и сломать dom дерево html. А это бакги в вёрстке в функционале, снова кастыли, кастыли и  т.д. Какая конкретно задача стоит перед тобой?

Comment: https://swtch.com/~rsc/regexp/regexp1.html

Comment: @Naumov, задача такая: при отображении страницы со статьей заменить некоторые "кодовые" фразы на HTML-теги. В основном, открывающую и закрывающую фразы, но не всегда. Например, `[quote]...[/quote]`. Это не реализация BB-кодов, как может показаться из примера, скорее, вынужденное расширение функционала текстового редактора, без чего пришлось бы писать кучу кода для вызова и обработки диалоговых окон редактора. В настоящее время делаю при помощи `str_replace` и двух массивов: в одном - входящие строки для замены, а в другом - то, на что надо заменить.

Comment: В любом случае много писать придёться так как надо искать правильную скобочную послежовательность к примеру. `[quote]...[/quote] .. [/quote]`  поэтому придёться всё равно реализовывать стэк анализировать его и после если всё верно уже искать и заменять на нужное. Так что лучше реализовать всплывающие окна и т.д. и т.п.

Comment: Какой редактор если не секрет?

Comment: @Naumov, не секрет, это TinyMCE. Но в моей задаче всплывающие окна сделать совсем непросто - такое решение использовать нечто вроде BB-кодов пришло как раз из-за простоты реализации. Тут уж придется поверить на слово.) В любом случае, спасибо, буду смотреть в сторону `DomDocument`.

Comment: Простое решение на первый взгляд выливаеться в кастыли и большой объём кода, сложное решение иногда оказываеться быстрее и эфективнее "простого"